# Java Design Patterns Examples

Tags: java, design-patterns, aspectj

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Examples of GoF Design Patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673841/examples-of-gof-design-patterns)

for some university work I'm working on a new way (using AO) to implement design patterns.

So now basically need to find some "real-life" examples of usage of design patterns (namely adapter, proxy, singleton, factory and observer) inside Java applications so to isolate the very part of the code in which the certain DP is being used so to try and implement that part differently.
Any (not-so-big) java application, piece of java framework/library , github/googlecode project whatsoever will be much appreciated.

Comment: I cannot agree that your question is duplicate. So I'm answering. Actually the work you are trying to do is done already. Look here for more information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244165/how-can-we-implement-strategy-pattern-using-aspectj/7245274#7245274

Comment: Hmm, but the question is duplicate indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Spring Framework. It uses a number of different design patterns.